# What is the difference between query_cache_size vs query_cache_limit?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is the difference between the `query_cache_size` vs `query_cache_limit` parameter in MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: As a side note...  Efficiency degrades if `query_cache_size` is set higher than, say, 50M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `query_cache_limit` is the maximum size of a single individual cached query result whereas `query_cache_size` is the sum total of the individual cached query results.

[`query_cache_limit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_limit)

> Do not cache results that are larger than this number of bytes.

[`query_cache_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size)

> The amount of memory allocated for caching query results.

Comment: Most people set the 'limit' at 1%-10% of the 'size'.  In practice, it is usually better to turn off the cache.